# linking mean stack server to ionic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ionic-framework, mean-stack

Hey I'm very new to app creation and have been working with ionic for about a month now and I was wondering how do I get my application so that I can retrieve and send information to ionic through a mean stack. I've came across alot of tutorials on how to create a mean stack but not how to get the information to and from ionic.

ex1. I would like my login (standard ionic login) to query the username and password.

ex2. i would like to post data from my mongodb to ionic (already know how to do the mean stack really need help with linking it)

I hope I'm being clear and thank you for your responses.

Comment: MEAN is a server infrastructure: you need "something" to answer you app requests; i.e. backend server application... you are familiar with that concept?

Comment: Like angular? is that a backend server application?

Comment: Is there an example you know?

Comment: Angular is at the other end: presentation layer (data entry, validation, GUI, etc.); [here's a tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/) to implement a simple backend app using mongodb, express, node (the "pieces" in the MEAN stack). It maybe won't cover your actual setup, but at least will serve you as a start to comprehend the involved concepts. Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate your comments! One more question do you need all of those applications to connect a monogodb to ionic?

Comment: Actually yes. Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to allow end clients (e.g. a web app) to directly access (read / write) server resources.

For instance: what if you change your database software (from mongodb to another thing)? also, by accessing directly those resources, you're giving away the "keys" of your data to anyone who could inspect your client code (i.e. virtually everybody!) and nothing would stop them to make unwanted and unvalidated changes to your precious data. You need to develop a "layer" inside the server that could access your data and respond to client requests: that layer is a *backend server app*.

There are software (libraries) that helps with database access: instead of using a "low-level database language", these pieces of software abstract and encaptulates (wraps) for you those calls and ease the development of your server app. In MEAN stack (nodejs, express, mongodb) you could use [monk](https://github.com/Automattic/monk) as a data access library.

A rough diagram of your "app stack" (pun intended!) could be the following:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SOFTWARE IN YOUR SERVER                  | CLIENT APP (WEB BROWSER, MOBILE APP, ETC.) |
| mongodb <-> monk <-> backend server app <-> Javascript, native code, etc.             |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Your client app(s) could use only the api (interface) that your backend server app exposes. For instance: an Ionic framework app (i.e. Javascript code) could validate and clean (satinize, convert to JSON, etc.) user data and send it to the server app (by making Ajax calls to the server api). The server app then responds with some result data or status code / message that the client could in turn process and show to the end user.

The [tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/) in the comments its a good starting point. These are the main bits of code:

- In the server app (Node + Express):

  ```
  // Initialize database access
  var mongo = require('mongodb');
  var monk = require('monk');
  var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest2');

  . . .

  // define route (api endpoint) to get data (userlist collection in this case)
  router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
      var db = req.db;
      var collection = db.get('userlist');
      collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
          res.json(docs);
      });
  });
  ```
- In the client app (javascript): function to call backend api method

  ```
  // Fill table with data
  function populateTable() {

      // Empty content string
      var tableContent = '';

      // jQuery AJAX call for JSON
      $.getJSON( '/users/userlist', function( data ) {

          // process each item in returned JSON data
          $.each(data, function(){
              // process each data item...
          });

          // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
          $('#userList table tbody').html(tableContent);
      });
  };
  ```

As you can see, the client code calls (using Ajax) the web server through the exposed api endpoint `/users/userlist`: this call returns data back to the client. In the same manner, you could write code to make other [CRUD operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) on your server data; obviously a better example would require a list of parameters: data to filter, data to post, etc. But that's part of your server app design and architecture.

In this example, the technology happens to be all-javascript: the server app uses nodejs + express (javascript) and the client code (web or mobile app) also uses javascript; but the stack could be any combination of suitable technologies: in the backend you could use any server framework (php, python, asp.net, ruby on rails, etc.); the same applies to the client: any technology that could be used to integrate a remote data consumer can be used as the client.